# Compression difference between Rails on production server and in local production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I compare a local copy of our codebase running in Rails production mode to the same codebase running on an actual server, and use Webkit Inspector's Network tab to compare the size of concatenated javascript, I see a total of 36k on the live server and 99k on the local copy running in production mode.

I have been careful to precompile my assets, and I have assets.compress = true enabled.

The weird thing is that if I examine the concatenated JS, it IS minified identically in both cases. In other words, it LOOKS visually like compression is happening through the Asset Pipeline ... but the reported numbers differ wildly.

Relevant commands:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
rails s -e production
```

in the config:

```
 config.assets.compress = true
```

Any theories? Thanks.

Comment: Are those numbers both from HTTP requests made with empty caches? IIRC, if you are compressing (using gzip, for example) the files when you serve them, Webkit will display the compressed size the first time you fetch them, but the uncompressed size if they're cached locally and didn't need to be re-downloaded.

ETA: also, it occurs to me to ask: are your compression settings different for your local webserver vs your production webserver?

Comment: Maybe it has to do something with file system itself? Different FS could allocate the same file differently. And this may result in size variations.

Comment: @drewinglis I'm just using webrick as the local server, and Sprockets should be doing the compression if I have assets.compress = true (if I understand correctly). WKI shows two stacked numbers. For production, it shows 36k/99k, i.e. 3x compresssion. Locally, it shows 99k/99k, i.e. no compression. So maybe it is just a matter of local caching...

Comment: A thought: In production your webserver might serve the gzipped version of the asset file. It might be that Sprocket generates both compressed and uncompressed versions, and your Nginx instance or else in production send gzip-compressed content.

Comment: Thomas, I think you're right. The use case here was to try and get accurate counts for the extra weight of a JS library we wanted to add in, so the fact that locally running in production mode doesn't give you an accurate picture of production weights was a bit of a bummer. But we're still able to ballpark it pretty well. Thanks.